# Generate a random sparse matrix with N non-zero-elements

Tags: matlab

I've written a function that generates a sparse matrix of size `nxd`

and puts in each column 2 non-zero values.

```
function [M] = generateSparse(n,d)
    M = sparse(d,n);
    sz = size(M);
    nnzs = 2;
    val = ceil(rand(nnzs,n));
    inds = zeros(nnzs,d);
    for i=1:n
        ind = randperm(d,nnzs);
        inds(:,i) = ind;
    end 
    points = (1:n);
    nnzInds = zeros(nnzs,d);
    for i=1:nnzs
        nnzInd = sub2ind(sz, inds(i,:), points);
        nnzInds(i,:) =  nnzInd;
    end
    M(nnzInds) = val;
end
```

However, I'd like to be able to give the function another parameter **num-nnz** which will make it choose randomly **num-nnz** cells and put there 1.

I can't use [sprand](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprand.html) as it requires density and I need the number of non-zero entries to be in-dependable from the matrix size. And giving a density is basically dependable of the matrix size.

I am a bit confused on how to pick the indices and fill them... I did with a loop which is extremely costly and would appreciate help.

**EDIT:**
Everything has to be sparse. A big enough matrix will crash in memory if I don't do it in a sparse way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem close!

You could pick `num_nnz` random (unique) integers between 1 and the number of elements in the matrix, then assign the value 1 to the indices in those elements.

To pick the random unique integers, use `randperm`. To get the number of elements in the matrix use `numel`.

```
M = sparse(d, n); % create dxn sparse matrix
num_nnz = 10;     % number of non-zero elements
idx = randperm(numel(M), num_nnz); % get unique random indices
M(idx) = 1;       % Assign 1 to those indices
```